# Laravel Pusher beam configuration issue

Tags: laravel-8

[image]
how to solve this issue please help me

i am new on laravel please check the above issue

pusher beam not supporting  events version greater than 5

Comment: pleaes reply me as soon as possible

Comment: "_pusher beam not supporting events version greater than 5_" What do you want us to do here? Changing that is the package author's task. You could fork the package and fix it yourself.